# Doubt in Discrete-Event System Simulation by Jerry Banks,4th Edition

Tags: random

I'm new to the Math forum here, so pardon my question if it seems juvenile to some. I've googled intensively,gone through wikipedia,wolfram and after hitting dead ends everywhere have resorted to this site.

My query is this-

In chapter#8, "Random-Variate Generation", the problems are required to use a sequence of random numbers obtained from a table A.1 .

But I find no correlation between the random numbers used and the numbers in the table.
So how are the numbers generated exactly? Are they assumed??

Table A.1 is on page 501 in this link

http://books.google.com/books?id=b0lgHnfe3K0C&pg=PA501&lpg=PA501&dq=78166+82521&source=bl&ots=nR33GcAzGF&sig=9LQjAPyGxDDxz1QLsEeMwN_UytA&hl=en&ei=3TTeTbPyNoqJrAe6zPGOCg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CDUQ6AEwBTgo#v=onepage&q&f=false

And the random numbers used in my problem are :
R1=0.8353
R2=0.9952
R3=0.8004

How do you get these values of R1,R2,R3 from the table in the link???

If you cant view the table from the link up there, the table is as in the image shown below-
[image] 
     [image]

Comment: Can you reproduce the table here? I can't see the preview in the link you gave.

Comment: ive uploaded it, as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an hypothesis. Since three coefficients only are obtained from a whole bunch of data, these could summarize some properties of the sample considered. Statisticians often use the symbol R<sup>2</sup> for a [coefficient of determination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination), which, roughly speaking, measures the proportion of variability in a data set.

On the positive side, these are by definition between 0 and 1, like yours. On the negative side, one would still have to understand how *one* sample gave rise to *three* coefficients, perhaps the whole sample was split into three. (I was not able to check the pages around Table A.1 because I have access to no preview on googlebooks for this book.)